# JavaFX8 : BooleanBinding disabledProperty for content of textproperty not working

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Im trying to create a boolean binding for the disabled property of a node.
Node should be enabled if a textProperty value does end with a defined string:

```
myheckbox.disabledProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(()
                -> myLabel.getText().endsWith(".txt"), myLabel.textProperty()));
```

This does not compile due to:
The method bind(BooleanBinding) is undefined for the type ReadOnlyBooleanProperty

How can i bind this? The checkbox is disabled initially and should be enabled if the label contains a filename ending with ".txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to bind the wrong property. There's two properties related to the disabled state of a node:

1. [`Node#disabled`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#disabledProperty) (read-only)

   > Indicates whether or not this `Node` is disabled. A `Node` will become disabled if `disable` is set to true on either itself or one of its ancestors in the scene graph.
2. [`Node#disable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty) (read-write)

   > Defines the individual disabled state of this `Node`. Setting `disable` to true will cause this `Node` and any subnodes to become disabled. This property should be used only to set the disabled state of a `Node`. For querying the disabled state of a `Node`, the `disabled` property should instead be used, since it is possible that a `Node` was disabled as a result of an ancestor being disabled even if the individual `disable` state on this `Node` is false.

You need to bind the latter property.

```java
myheckbox.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(()
                -> myLabel.getText().endsWith(".txt"), myLabel.textProperty()));
```